# ng-show working, but doing opposite to what is expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

The function involves showing a drop down menu when a button is clicked, although there are some items I do not want to show, depending on the conditions.

```
        function dropdownMenu(params) {
        var ownFunction = params.data.functieMijnLicentieHouder;
        if (params.data.systeem === 'VVT' && (ownFunction || (!ownFunction && fwgAuthService.userHasClaim('FWGVVT FWG functieonderzoek'))) ){
            return '<div class="io-dropdown"><img src="img/arrow_blue_down.png" ng-click="vm.showMenu(data)"/>' +
                '<ul ng-show="data.showMenu" ng-mouseleave="data.showMenu = false">' +
                '<li>Inzien functiebeschrijving</li>' +
                '<li>Inzien functiemotivatie</li>' +
                '<li ng-show="!!ownFunction"> Muteren functiemotivatie </li>' + // if ownFunction is true.show
                '<li>it works</li>' +
                '</div>';
        } else if (params.data.systeem === 'FWG3' && (ownFunction || (!ownFunction && fwgAuthService.userHasClaim('FWGVVT FWG functieonderzoek'))) ){
            return '<div class="io-dropdown"><img src="img/arrow_blue_down.png" ng-click="vm.showMenu(data)"/>' +
                '<ul ng-show="data.showMenu" ng-mouseleave="data.showMenu = false">' +
                '<li>Inzien functiemotivatie</li>' +
                '<li>Inzien FWG 3 Indeling</li>'+
                '</ul>' +
                '</div>';
        }
    }
```

The value of `ownFunction` is true initially, I checked with console.log before if statement and ng-show do work, but it shows opposite results i.e. False when True and True when False. I can not understand this behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ownFunction should be in $scope object for ng-show to work.

Instead of

```
var ownFunction = params.data.functieMijnLicentieHouder;
```

try

```
$scope.ownFunction = params.data.functieMijnLicentieHouder;
```

Answer (score -1):

From a quick look, are you sure you need two `!!` in your `ng-show`, could this be the reason here?

`'<li ng-show="!!ownFunction"> Muteren functiemotivatie </li>'`